# Using Apigee or usergrid REST API, how can I query entities by a list of UUIDs?

Tags: apigee, usergrid, apigee-baas

How can I query for entities using a list of UUIDs in Apigee/usergrid using the REST API? I'm using Apigee for sending push notifications via REST API, and have it working correctly for 1 device or all devices, but would like to target a subset of devices. I've poured over the documentation, but can't find anything. Has anyone been able to do this?

The strange thing is that I can use GET to query the device, but the equivalent POST to send a push does not work.

```
// This works
[GET] https://api.usergrid.com/{{ORG_ID}}/{{APP_ID}}/devices/;ql=UUID=3646781A-D83E-4FD9-B873-C212BA2CD4DD?access_token={{ACCESS_TOKEN}}

// This does not work
[POST]
https://api.usergrid.com/{{ORG_ID}}/{{APP_ID}}/devices;ql=select * where uuid=3646781A-D83E-4FD9-B873-C212BA2CD4DD/notifications?access_token={{ACCESS_TOKEN}}
```

The response from the POST request says no devices found

```
// this also works for sending a push
[POST]
https://api.usergrid.com/{{ORG_ID}}/{{APP_ID}}/devices/3646781A-D83E-4FD9-B873-C212BA2CD4DD/notifications?access_token={{ACCESS_TOKEN}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a query with the OR operator:

?ql=uuid=someuuid or uuid=someuuid

Comment: I can't seem to get this syntax working. I've updated my question with examples.